# '$cd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file error message

Tags: shell

newbie here.

i was just learning on how to code in java just out of curiosity. I was trying to change directory from my terminal with $cd and it came back as "'$cd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Has anyone else face the same problem ?

thankyou!

Comment: what does this have to do with `java` or `intellij-idea`?

Comment: You should seriously read about how to ask a question here. I'll help because it sucks to be confused and downvoted, but for real, check out the getting started here to avoid this in the future. The `$` represents that something is to be typed in a terminal, so you should be typing `cd` not `$cd`. You could easily figure this out for yourself with google though. "cd in cmd example"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are following an instruction like:

```
$ cd myfolder
$ somecommand
$ anothercommand
```

The $ character appears in Linux command windows to tell you that you can start entering a command. Windows does usually display a ">" instead. You shall not enter this character. So enter "cd", not "$cd".